# Angular2 parsing json object using observables

Tags: mysql, json, angular, observable

I am working on Angular2 and MySQL, need some advice on injectable services using observables,

I have created a service to get all the data from the api using `getTable()`, but now I'm stuck with implementing an another service to filter and parse the json data and use only `epoch_time`  and `temp` from the data object (below) and subscribe to it using Observables. I'm using Angular2 V2.2

**service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class TabuleService {

      //private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      private _Url = 'http://localhost:3000';  // URL to web api

      constructor(private _http: Http) {}

      getTable(): Observable<Tabule[]> {
        const url = this._Url+'/temperature';
        return this._http.get(url)
                   .map(res => res.json())
                   .catch(this.handleError);
      }

       getTemp(): Observable<testing[]> {
        const url = this._Url+'/temperature';
        return this._http.get(url)
                   .map(this.extractData)
                   //.filter(temp=>temp.mac==='3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-32')
                   .catch(this.handleError);
      }            

    private extractData(res: Response){
      let body =res.json();
      console.log(body.data);
      return body.data || { };

    }
```

**data  Object**

```
    epoch_time_stamp:1486257208633
    mac:"3s-ds-23-sf-xx-xx-xx"
    task_id:2
    temp:"23"
    time_stamp:"2017-02-05T01:13:28.000Z"

    epoch_time_stamp:1486257208733
    mac:"3s-ds-23-sf-xx-xx-xx"
    task_id:3
    temp:"26"
    time_stamp:"2017-02-05T01:15:28.000Z"
```

Comment: in the .map() you can modify that object which is coming from api. you just need to perform normal js code. extractData() will return whole data of response object.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is

Comment: i'm trying to achieve data in only with these properties
        temp:"26"
        epoch_time_stamp:1486257208633

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.filter` will not work for the problem you are describing. On your `.map` method you need to add logic that 'cleans' your data as you saw fit.

e.g.:

```
getTemp(): Observable<testing[]> {
    const url = this._Url+'/temperature';
    return this._http.get(url)
        .map(res => {
            let temp = res.json();
            //Add logic here that loops through temp and cleans value
            return temp;
            }).catch(this.handleError);
        }
```

Comment: thankyou...first im filtering the data based on mac_id i came up with this approach 

        var data2=data.filter(function(da){ return da.mac=="43-d3-f4-    d3-5v-3r"
                        }) 
now im try to loop using foreach method but im unable to find the error the return type is undefined

         data2.forEach(function (el)
              { return {time:el.time, temp:el.temp}
    }
   ) 
@nzjun

Comment: Hi Ram. Try using arrow function if you can use ES6 syntax. Also, you may want to collate your data rather than returning 1 element at a time. var data = {}; data2.forEach((el) => {  data.push({time:el.time, temp:el.temp}) }); return data;

Comment: Thankyou for your support. I understood now